# wrapping a div around html5 semantic tags?

Tags: css, html

this might seem a very weird question but i've been wondering the answer to it for a while now and couldn't find anything on the web about it (if i did miss it im sorry).

Anyway, what would be more "conventional" html5 way of using a div but also using the html5 semantic markup.

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Some header</h1>
    </header>
</div>
```

Would the following code above be better markup than the code below?

```
<header>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <h1>Some header</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Or does it have no effect what so ever ? or would you just add a class onto the html5 semantic initially and get rid of div altogether ?

p.s this is my first post, please let me know if it is too 'broad' of a question to ask.

Comment: Better to remove the `div` entirely and add the `header-wrapper` class to the semantic element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are perfectly acceptable and valid markup, as both the **[`<header>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)** and the **[`<div>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)** support **[flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)** for their children, and both elements **are** flow content. As for which approach is more preferable, it comes down almost entirely to personal preference.

However, having said that, it kind of defeats the purpose to make use of **both** a `<header>` and a `<div class="header-wrapper">`, if you're not going to have any content in `<header>` other than the wrapper (or vice-versa). What would be a better option would be to make use of only one tag.

**Technically** opting just for the `<header>` element would be a better option, as the very element name *describes* that code within should comprise the header of the document, and the name can be read and interpreted more easily. As far as I'm aware, there's no difference in terms of SEO, though someone browsing through the DOM would, in theory, spend less time 'deconstructing' a `<header>` tag.

However, again, choice at the end of the day really does come down to personal preference.

Hope this helps :)